# How to give large spacing in HTML

Tags: html, tabs, spacing

I know we use `&nbsp;` for spacing in HTML, but what if I need to give large spaces of around 2 or 3 tabs?
I need my page to look as below:

```
<html>
<body>
 <b>
A &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
B &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
C </b>
<br>
<b> 
D &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
E &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
F </b>
</body>
</html>
```

This will look like:

A        B        C

D        E        F

I cannot define word-spacing, as A may or may not be a single word. So defining this property separates that.

Please help me out

Comment: can you use div's for containing this content ? if possible then place content in 6 different div's  and give them width and positions.

Comment: it should be done by  either table or   css

Comment: giving a try for table, using tab-spacing. need to check if it is working.

Comment: can you please provide sample code for table/div?

Answer (score 2):

You can define a class in css

```
.tab{
     Padding-left:20px;
}
```

And then in your paragraph use

```
Text here <span class="tab"><\> more text here
```

Comment: I tried padding, but it worked only for the first line and first column, ie only for A, and not for B and C.

Comment: Can you paste your html?

Comment: <div class="tab">
<h2>Subjects</h2>
<a href="sm_polity_home.html">Polity</a>
<a href="Home.html">Miscellenous</a>
<a href="Home.html">World</a>
</div>

Comment: If you want multiple tabs you'll have to insert spans with the class tab into your dog

Comment: <div> <h2>Subjects</h2> <a href="sm_polity_home.html">Polity</a><span class="tab"></span> <a href="Home.html">Miscellenous</a><span class="tab"></span> <a href="Home.html">World</a> </div>

Answer (score 1):

This is a styling question. You can do this in your CSS file, try changing your padding-left and margin-left values.

Comment: Tried, but didn't get it the way I need.